# Какой тип данных может содержаться в суперглобальном массиве $_POST?

Tags: php

Это всегда строки или нет? Например `file_get_contents('php://input');` всегда читает содержимое из тела POST запроса именно в строку.

Comment: А какой вариант еще ты ожидаешь? Булево значение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как и большинство протоколов интернета, HTTP - протокол текстовый. И все данные передаются в нем в виде строк.

Если хочется передавать информацию о типе переменной, то надо использовать соответствующий формат, например json.

Если же говорить о массиве $_POST, то, как правильно пишет cheops в соседнем ответе, помимо строк в нем могут содержаться и массивы, в соответствии с соглашением о парсинге имен переменных определенного формата.

Answer (score 3):

Вообще говоря вы можете посылать HTTP-методом POST любые данные, в том числе бинарные, однако, интерпретатор PHP при формировании суперглобального массива `$_POST` будет ориентироваться только на данные, оформленные по CGI-соглашению. Т.е. если методом POST будет отправлена последовательность

```
hello=world&number=1
```

Вы получите в `$_POST` два элемента `$_POST['hello']` и `$_POST['number']`. Да, их значения всегда будут строками, в данном случае "world" и "1". Если вы пошлете методом POST последовательность вида

```
14±3ды§ва`оЁыв3
```

То суперглобальный массив `$_POST` будет пустым, так как анализатор не сможет выделить элементы и значения из этой последовательности. Однако, вы сможете прочитать эту строку при помощи `file_get_contents('php://input')`. Таким образом, вы можете пересылать на сервер любые данные, например, бинарные или файлы. В PHP для файлов предназначен специальный суперглобальный массив `$_FILES`, он так же анализирует тело POST-запроса и если обнаруживает загрузку файлов, заполняет массив данными. К php://input прибегают так же в том случае, если Web-сервер поддерживает отличный от POST метод, например PUT для которого в PHP нет отдельного суперглобального массива.

Comment: Т.е. проще говоря, в суперглобальном массиве $_POST всегда содержатся только строки. Так?

Comment: @Khipster, да или массивы строк, если имя принимает вид name[]=dlfsdl&name[]=dfdsl

Comment: вообще-то, во втором примере здесь тоже строка. А "бинарные данные" - это уже интерпретация.

Comment: Собственно, нигде не написано, что это не строки. Просто во втором случае не будет заполнен суперглобальный массив $_POST, так как строка не является CGI-набором параметров.